# Tmlib.js0.3 androidのバックキーやホームキーの制御

Tags: android, tmlib.js

tmlib.jsを使ってandroidアプリを作成中ですが、バックキーやホームボタンの制御のやりかたがわかりません。
バックキーを押すと

"終了メニュー"
"終了しますか？"
"はい","いいえ"

のような画面を出したいです。
表示してあるときは、app.stop
"はい"を押すとホーム画面にもどり
"いいえ"を押すとapp.start

ホームキーをおすと
ホーム画面に行き
再び立ち上げると
終了メニューが表示されている
後はバックキーを押したときと同じ動き

よろしくお願いします。